# EF query with group by, where clause and 'HAVING' condition as distinct count

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to get the EF equivalent of the following SQL Server query, where it returns a list of all customers who have distinct product count of more than 1:

```
SELECT [customer]
FROM [Orders]
where product = 'foo'
OR product = 'bar'
GROUP BY customer

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(product)) > 1
```

This is what I have at the moment as EF method syntax code:

```
var customerList = dbContext.GroupBy(l => l.customer)
.Select(g => new 
{ 
 Customer = g.Key, 
 Count = g.Select(l => l.product).Distinct().Count(),
 Product = g.Select(f => f.product).FirstOrDefault()
}).Where(w => w.Count > 1 && (w.Product == "foo" || w.Product == "bar"))
.Select(s => s.Customer).ToList();
```

This returns an incorrect list as below:

```
  customer    Products
  --------------------
  Customer1   Foo, Bar
  Customer2   Foo, Bar
  Customer3   Foo, Bar
  Customer4   Foo, Foo
```

Expected list must be:

```
  customer    Products
  --------------------
  Customer1   Foo, Bar
  Customer2   Foo, Bar
  Customer3   Foo, Bar
```

Comment: What if you put where with "(w.Product == "foo" || w.Product == "bar")" filter before GroupBy?

Comment: @yurish - Thanks, yes, putting the where clause before GroupBy does fetch the correct result, my final EF query is like this:`var customerList = dbContext.Where(w.Product == "foo" || w.Product == "bar").GroupBy(l => l.customer)
.Select(g => new 
{ 
 Customer = g.Key, 
 Count = g.Select(l => l.product).Distinct().Count()
}).Where(w => w.Count > 1)
.Select(s => s.Customer).ToList();`